# How to receive the live stream of Instagram in react-native App

Tags: api, react-native, video-streaming, instagram, live

Is there any solution to let me receive the live stream of specific Instagram account (for example my Instagram account not any account) in react-native app?!

I mean does Instagram API have this feature to send a live stream of an account?!
Even webView is OK.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to receive a livestream through the API, only through their app. The only media you can get through the API are posted photos/videos. However, it seems instagram is [deprecating its API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/). Until dec 11, 2018, you can "read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf", but if you only want to receive the data from your account, it probably will still work until early 2020. However, after that, the API will only work for moderation of business accounts. So, it probably isn't a good idea if you are working on a product.